# Vue component only shows up as <componentName> Tag and didnt gets rendered

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

One component on my vue site isn`t rendered correctly. It is registered like a lot of other components, they are working fine. But when i call  only  appears in the DOM. Why is this component behaving so strangely?

/index.vue

```
<template>
    <emailResults></emailResults>
</template>
<script>
import { emailResults } from ../components;
export default {
  components: {
    emailResults
  }
};
</script>
```

/emailResults.vue

```
<template>
...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'emailResults',
}
</script>
```

/index.js

```
import emailResults from './emailResults'

export{
  emailResults
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more because I didn't get what you're asking

Comment: Ok so the component isn´t rendered corretly but is importet like other components they are working fine. In the same time i get a    [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <emailResults> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.   but name is declared. I am confused.

Comment: You have to pass name of the component here emailResults
} from ../components;

Comment: I tried this with the export default {
  name: '}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an index.vue and index.js file. Depeding on your bundler's setup, it might try to import from the wrong file here:

```
import {
  emailResults
} from ../components;
```

Try being explicit:

```
import {
  emailResults
} from ../components/index.js;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also just noticed that Vue generated this error even though the name is set.

Comment: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <emailResults> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: Yeah this error comes up because you did not register the component, likely because the import statement produced `undefined` because of what I described.

Comment: Ok thanks but in my opinion the index.js imports the component and the index.vue is only the starting point of the app which uses the components.

Comment: Well, console.log `emailResults ` in your index.vue file and see what you get.