# dynamic component doesn't work as intended in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I need to dynamically show a success of fail component based on the result of the api call, this is my example: 
**SCRIPT**

```
const loader = ref(true);
const resultPage = ref("");

this.getResult()
.then((response : boolean) => {
    response ? resultPage.value = 'success' : resultPage.value = 'fail';
})
.finally(() => {
    loader.value = false
})
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<component
   v-if="!loader"
   :is="resultPage"
   :key="resultPage"
 />
```

The component i created in my project is Success.vue and Fail.vue (using **composition API**).
I simply imported them:

```
import Fail from "./result/Fail.vue";
import Success from "./result/Success.vue";
```

The value of my **ref** ***resultPage*** is 'success' or 'fail'.
I noticed that if importing the component normally works, this is the case:

```
<success v-if="!loader" />
```

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a while i decided to re-read the documentation and i found this little paragraph which i didn't read the first time :_) 
**Registration is not required if you pass the component itself to is rather than its name, e.g. in < script setup >.**

Basically i modified my code like this

```
const loader = ref(true);
const resultPage = ref({});
this.getResult()
.then((response : boolean) => {
    resultPage.value = response ? Success : Fail;
})
.finally(() => {
    loader.value = false
})
```

I think this issue is also related to [Vue component only shows up as <componentName> Tag and didnt gets rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021597/vue-component-only-shows-up-as-componentname-tag-and-didnt-gets-rendered?rq=3).

I'll keep it here to avoid making another one like me lose 2 hours of time

Comment: I'd suggest `.then((response) => (resultPage.value = response ? Success : Fail))` for improved readability.